# How to mock the httplib2

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I use httplib to create connection from my client to api. But when I writing unittest for httplib2 , i get stuck with httplib2 trying to find set_debuglevel function.Anyone have some cool solution , please and welcome :)

Comment: Are you making calls to your own app? Or external resources? And are the unit tests for django or something else?

Comment: @Phrogz, you just done gone and made me spill my coffee. @vernomcrp you might try Michael Foord`s mocking library (http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/). It's got fantastic docs. Try patching the `request()` method and see if that avoids any nasty internals.

Comment: jbcurtin, yes i making calls  to my own app. @Filip Dupanovic ,yahh thank fot your advice.